# "Dictionary" Undeclared

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a dictionary in C. Basically, the user creates the dictionary himself, inputting a word and then a definition. I've created a function where the dictionary is displayed, showing each entry and its definition. However, I'm getting this error:

error: ‘dictionary’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Here's the code that I've written:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display (char *array) {
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<11; ++i)
        printf("%s %s", dictionary[i][0], dictionary[i][1]);
}

int main(void) {
    char *dictionary[10][2];
    int command;
    int i;

    while (command != 3) {
        printf ("1. Define or 2. Lookup or 3. Exit");
        scanf ("%d", &command);

        if (command == 1) {
            for (i=0; i<11; ++i) {
                printf("Please enter a word to define:");
                scanf("%s\n", dictionary[i][0]); 
                printf("Please enter its definition:");
                scanf("%s", dictionary[i][1]);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (command == 2)
            display(dictionary);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Many answers below explain what's wrong in your program snippet. In case you're interested in a formal treatment of what's going on, read about the difference between the *formal* and the *actual* parameters.

Answer (score 4):

`dictionary` is a local variable in a different function.
Your parameter is named `array`.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `dictionary` is out of scope. Try this,

```
if (command == 2) {
    for (i=0; i<11; ++i)
        printf("%s %s", dictionary[i][0], dictionary[i][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `display`, dictionary is not declared. That simple.

Answer (score 0):

In display function change `dictionary` to `array`

Answer (score 0):

`dictionary` is a local variable inside the `main`, which cannot be accessed directly from your function; instead, you have your parameter `array` for that use, that is bound to the first argument specified when the function is called.

But there's another problem: you declared the parameter incorrectly. Multidimensional arrays have to be passed in a particular way:

```
void display (char array[][2]) {
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<11; ++i)
        printf("%s %s", array[i][0], array[i][1]);
}
```

I.e., all the dimensions (except optionally the first) must be specified, otherwise the compiler cannot know how to reach the elements you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

After you've changed `dictionary` to `array` within `display()`, you may get other weird behaviour...

```
char *dictionary[10][2];

for (i=0; i<11; ++i) {
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error