# "Subscripted Value is Neither Array Nor Pointer" Error in Dictionary Program

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a dictionary program. The user inputs a entry and a definition. I'm running into a problem with the display function I've written. I'm getting this error:

```
dictionary.c:7: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display (char *array) {
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<11; ++i)
        printf("%s %s\n", array[i][0], array[i][1]);
}

int main(void) {
    char *dictionary[10][2];
    int command;
    int i;

    while (command != 3) {
        printf ("1. Define or 2. Lookup or 3. Exit");
        scanf ("%d", &command);

        if (command == 1) {
            for (i=0; i<11; ++i) {
                printf("Please enter a word to define:");
                scanf("%s\n", dictionary[i][0]); 
                printf("Please enter its definition:");
                scanf("%s", dictionary[i][1]);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (command == 2)
            display(dictionary);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure I understand. Isn't dictionary an array? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: `printf("%s %s\n", array[i][0], array[i][1]);` - your `array` parameter is a one-dimensional `char` array?

Comment: The next problem you'll run into (definitions with more than one word) can be avoided by not using `scanf()`; use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: You should turn up your compiler's warning flags and pay attention to what it complains about, turning the warnings into errors is also a good idea.

Comment: How do I turn up its warning flags?

Comment: It depends on which compiler you're using.  For gcc, `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra` is a good start.

Comment: It's important to show us *all* the diagnostic messages you get.  Surely your compiler would have complained about the `display(dictionary);` call on line 30.

Comment: You show us just another error with seemingly exactly the same code as in your question 1 hour before. Perhaps you should first try to read up a bit about C and its concepts and not immediately ask for help when you encounter the slightest difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

In display(), array is declared as a pointer, so it could be treated as a single-dimensional array; but you are using it as a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: Pointers aren't allowed to be 2-dimensional arrays?

Comment: @user1064913: how could they? Do you have an idea on how a multidimensional array work? Anyhow, look [at my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966216/dictionary-undeclared/8966258#8966258) to your previous question.

Comment: Pointer are not arrays, and arrays are not pointers.  Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com).

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `array` to the function `display()` does not have the correct type.  If you wish to pass `dictionary` to it, it should have the type `char *(*)[2]`:

```
void display (char *array[][2])
{
```

You will then run into another problem, which is that you never initialised the `char *` values that make up the array `dictionary`.  You can't pass them to `scanf()` until they point somewhere sensible.

Answer (score 1):

```
void display (char *array) {
...
printf("%s %s\n", array[i][0], array[i][1]);
```

`array` is of type `char*`, so `array[i]` is of type `char`.  You can't apply the `[]` indexing operator to a `char`.

```
char *dictionary[10][2];
...
display(dictionary);
```

`display()` requires an argument of type `char*`.  `dictionary` is of type `char*[10][2]`, or 10-element array of 2-element arrays of pointer to char.  It's implicitly converted to a pointer to a 2-element array of pointer to char, but that's still not compatible with `char*`.

Some things to keep in mind:

A 2-dimensional array is simply an array of arrays.

In most contexts, an array expression is implicitly converted to a pointer to the array's first element; see section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com) for details.

When you use the indexing operator, x[y]`,`x`is a pointer and`y` is an integer.  The pointer value is typically the result of converting an array, but it can be just a pointer (that happens to point to the first element of an array).

Oh, and `scanf` with a `"%s"` format is dangerous.  It reads arbitrarily many characters into the specified target array; you can't limit it to the size of the array.